# Append list of dictionaries to a single Dataframe with dictionary keys as columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have something like this:

```
  dns_result = 
[{"DNS":[dns.com, dns2.com], IP:[10.10.10.10, 10.10.10.11]} 
 {"DNS":[something.com, something2.com],"IP":[50.50.50.10, 50.50.50.51]}]
```

What I would like to have is this:

| DNS | IP |
| --- | --- |
| dns.com | 10.10.10.10 |
| dns2.com | 10.10.10.11 |
| something.com | 50.50.50.10 |
| something2.com | 50.50.50.11 |

What I have tried:

1.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': dns_result.keys(), "values": dns_result.values()})
df_final = pd.concat([df_final, df], ignore_index=True)
```

2. 

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dns_result, orient='index').T
```

3. 

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dns_result)
```

4. 

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0: {k: v for d in dns_result
                             for k,v in d.items()}}, orient='index')
```

5. 

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.Series, dns_result)).to_frame().T
```

Some return a dataframe with 2 rows that contain the dictionary values and other just one row with all values and keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine intermediate dataframes with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame, dns_result))
```

---

```
              DNS           IP
0         dns.com  10.10.10.10
1        dns2.com  10.10.10.11
0   something.com  50.50.50.10
1  something2.com  50.50.50.51
```

---

Time measurements:

```
In [457]: %timeit pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame, dns_result))
327 µs ± 2.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [458]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(dns_result).apply(pd.Series.explode)
485 µs ± 1.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `pd.Series.explode`:

```
import pandas as pd 

dns_result = [{"DNS":["dns.com", "dns2.com"], "IP":["10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.11"]} ,
 {"DNS":["something.com", "something2.com"],"IP":["50.50.50.10", "50.50.50.51"]}]

df = pd.DataFrame(dns_result).apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

Output:

```
              DNS           IP
0         dns.com  10.10.10.10
0        dns2.com  10.10.10.11
1   something.com  50.50.50.10
1  something2.com  50.50.50.51
```